# Getting PostId for CommentId using Autoform for Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

Without the autoform, normally, we will do the below to submit comment:

comment-submit.js

```
 'submit form': function(e, template) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var $body = $(e.target).find('[name=body]');
     var status = {
       body: $body.val(),
       postId: template.data._id
     };
```

We can inject the postId into the each comment.

How to do that with Autoform?

I had try with this near the comment collection:

```
 Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments');

 Comments.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
   doc.postId = Posts.findOne()._id; 
 });



 Comments.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
   body: {
     type: String,
     autoform: {
       'label-type': 'placeholder',
       placeholder: 'Add your comment…'
     }
   },
   postId: {
     type: String
   }
 }));
```

It's work but it always get the postId of the 1st post in the collection even it is actually the 2nd, 3rd or other than 1st post.

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`collection.findOne()` always returns the first document that was inserted into a collection. So the nicest way to do this, that comes to my mind, is a hidden field. Just add a field to your `autoForm`

```
{{ > afQuickField name="postId" value=_id style="display: hidden;" }}
```

This solution will work without any hooks or special attributes.